# Accidentally made my whole C drive a local git repository

Tags: git

I am new to Git and wanted to try it out. I can't remember how I did it but now everytime I create a Visual Studio project it adds Git source control automatically and the changes are all my files from my C drive. How do I fix this?

Comment: @Christoph isn't that better than to lose your history?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you're beginner so you just created git repository, AND you don't have any important branches/history you can delete folder named .git in root of drive C.

Comment: What you write in one line is really dangerous. Please explain when you solution is suitable.

Comment: @Christoph You're right. Just edited it.